# Is it possible to create a single sql script to both create a database and to populate it with tables?

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql

When using the `psql` command-line tool to create a database, what I usually do (because I've seen it previously work and I don't really know any other way of doing things) is to:

1. Start off by creating a new user `U` (`CREATE USER U WITH PASSWORD 'U'`);
2. Then create a database named `U` (`CREATE DATABASE U`);
3. Quit `psql` and start it again with `psql -U U`
4. Start creating tables (`CREATE TABLE T()`).

The problem this imposes is that it doesn't work that well with SQL scripts. I'd prefer to just have one single .sql file where the full db creation could take place. Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can put all that into a SQL script. But after creating the database you need to change the connection to the newly created database using `\connect`. But I wonder why you are constantly creating a new database. Usually you just create a database once, and then use it. I most environments you wouldn't be allowed to provide a script like that. Creating a database (and creating users) is usually done through the DBA.

Comment: Hi. I just want to make a create script so that new developers of the system can easily create a db on their environments. But of course I could just do a bash script.

Comment: As I said: you can do that using one single SQL script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
psqluser="U"   # username
psqlpass="U"   # password
psqldb="U"   # db

sudo printf "CREATE USER $psqluser WITH PASSWORD '$psqlpass';\nCREATE DATABASE $psqldb WITH OWNER $psqluser;\nGRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database $psqldb TO $psqluser;" > createdb.sql

sudo -u postgres psql -f createdb.sql

echo "Populating inserting.sql"
sudo -u postgres psql -d $psqldb -f inserting.sql
```

where inserting.sql is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    id serial,
    description text
);


ALTER TABLE T OWNER TO U;


INSERT INTO T(description) VALUES ('description 1');
INSERT INTO T(description) VALUES ('description 2');


ALTER TABLE ONLY T ADD CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Comment: The `create table` will be run against the database that you initially connected to. You need to switch the connection once the new database is created using `\connect` in `psql`

Comment: You are right, thanks for comment. Maybe all can be done with a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the user and database, you can use `\connect` command to change the connection to the newly created database.

```
create user arthur with password 'secret';
create database arthur_db owner arthur;

\connect dbname=arthur_db user=arthur password=secret

-- create the tables and populate them
create table items
(
  id serial primary key,
  item_name text
);

insert into items (item_name) values ('Towel'), ('Peanuts');
```

---

`\connect` is specific to `psql` so the above only works with `psql`, not with other SQL clients.

If you have users that prefer other SQL clients, it might be a good idea to split up the creation of the database and user and the script to setup the database tables.

You can still use a single script that includes those two, so that users using `psql` can run a single script. Users using a different SQL client can manually run the two scripts and establish the connection themselves:

```
\i create_db_and_user.sql 
\connect dbname=arthur_db user=arthur password=secret
\i setup_tables.sql
```